# Box.net acting as Identity Provider (Idp)

Tags: box-api

Any roadmap for Box acting as an IdentityProvider (using OpenId) so that my application can rely on Box for login/authentication?

Answer (score 0):

A fascinating question, but one that really isn't suited for StackOverflow.  Product direction questions are much more suited to sending us a direct email (api at box).  Please explain what you are trying to do, and we can talk to you about how we might work with you to solve your business needs.